# iterrows pandas get next rows value

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a df in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])
```

I want to iterate over rows in df. For each row i want row`s value and next row`s value
Something like(it does not work):

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
     print row['value']
     i1, row1 = next(df.iterrows())
     print row1['value']
```

As a result I want

```
'AA'
'BB'
'BB'
'CC'
'CC'
*Wrong index error here
```

At this point i have mess way to solve this

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0])
   print df.irow(i)['value']
   print df.irow(i+1)['value']
```

Is there more efficient way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly, your "messy way" is ok, there's nothing wrong with using indices into the dataframe, and this will not be too slow. iterrows() itself isn't terribly fast.

A version of your first idea that would work would be:

```
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
_, last = row_iterator.next()  # take first item from row_iterator
for i, row in row_iterator:
    print(row['value'])
    print(last['value'])
    last = row
```

The second method could do something similar, to save one index into the dataframe:

```
last = df.irow(0)
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    print(last)
    print(df.irow(i))
    last = df.irow(i)
```

When speed is critical you can always try both and time the code.

Comment: I believe the 2nd line of the first option should read:
`_, last = row_iterator.next()`

Comment: For Python3 folks use either next(row_iterator) or row_iterator__next__()

Comment: In this example what does the `_,` do? Why can't I just do `last = next(row_iterator)` and which of the [five operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) is it performing here?

Comment: "_" is a valid character for an identifier name, and can even be used on it's own.  In reality it's such a meaningless name that people often use it to indicate the value is not used.  You can't just do what you're asking because this iterator returns a tuple that needs to be unpacked.

Answer (score 15):

There is a `pairwise()` function example in the `itertools` document:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])

for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    print i1, i2, row1["value"], row2["value"]
```

Here is the output:

```
0 1 AA BB
1 2 BB CC
```

But, I think iter rows in a `DataFrame` is slow, if you can explain what's the problem you want to solve, maybe I can suggest some better method.

Comment: This is very good. I was working on a similar problem to the original question and this solved my issue perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: In Python3 you no longer need to import `izip` -- the inbuilt `zip` provides the functionality [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/izip-not-working-in-python-3-x)

Comment: direct link to Python3 `itertools` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 10):

I would use shift() function as follows:

```
df['value_1'] = df.value.shift(-1)
[print(x) for x in df.T.unstack().dropna(how = 'any').values];
```

which produces

```
AA
BB
BB
CC
CC
```

This is how the code above works:

Step 1) Use shift function

```
df['value_1'] = df.value.shift(-1)
print(df)
```

produces

```
value value_1
0    AA      BB
1    BB      CC
2    CC     NaN
```

step 2) Transpose:

```
df = df.T
print(df)
```

produces:

```
          0   1    2
value    AA  BB   CC
value_1  BB  CC  NaN
```

Step 3) Unstack:

```
df = df.unstack()
print(df)
```

produces:

```
0  value       AA
   value_1     BB
1  value       BB
   value_1     CC
2  value       CC
   value_1    NaN
dtype: object
```

Step 4) Drop NaN values

```
df = df.dropna(how = 'any')
print(df)
```

produces:

```
0  value      AA
   value_1    BB
1  value      BB
   value_1    CC
2  value      CC
dtype: object
```

Step 5) Return a Numpy representation of the DataFrame, and print value by value:

```
df = df.values
[print(x) for x in df];
```

produces:

```
AA
BB
BB
CC
CC
```

Comment: This one worked very well thank you. This line ```df['value_1'] = df.value.shift(-1)``` was all that I needed to solve my similar requirement. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

a combination of answers gave me a very fast running time. 
using the **shift** method to create new column of next row values,
then using the **row_iterator**  function as @alisdt did,
but here i changed it from **iterrows** to **itertuples** which is 100
times faster.

my script is for iterating dataframe of duplications in different length and add
one second for each duplication so they all be unique.

```
# create new column with shifted values from the departure time column
df['next_column_value'] = df['column_value'].shift(1)
# create row iterator that can 'save' the next row without running for loop
row_iterator = df.itertuples()
# jump to the next row using the row iterator
last = next(row_iterator)
# because pandas does not support items alteration i need to save it as an object
t = last[your_column_num]
# run and update the time duplications with one more second each
for row in row_iterator:
    if row.column_value == row.next_column_value:
         t = t + add_sec
         df_result.at[row.Index, 'column_name'] = t
    else:
         # here i resetting the 'last' and 't' values
         last = row
         t = last[your_column_num]
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved also by `izip`ping the dataframe (iterator) with an offset version of itself.

Of course the indexing error cannot be reproduced this way.

Check this out

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import izip

df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])   

for id1, id2 in izip(df.iterrows(),df.ix[1:].iterrows()):
    print id1[1]['value']
    print id2[1]['value']
```

which gives

```
AA
BB
BB
CC
```