# Python Pandas iterrows() with previous values

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe  in the form:

```
            A           B       K      S
2012-03-31  NaN         NaN     NaN    10
2012-04-30  62.74449    15.2    71.64   0
2012-05-31  2029.487    168.8   71.64   0
2012-06-30  170.7191    30.4    71.64   0
```

I trying to create a function that  replace df['S']  using df['S'][index-1] value.

for example:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows:
     if index = 1: 
         pass
     else:
         df['S'] = min(df['A'] + df['S'][index-1]?? - df['B'], df['K'])
```

but i dont know how to get df['S'][index - 1]

Comment: For current/previous rows using `iterrows()`, see also, [iterrows pandas get next rows value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151722/343215).

Answer (score 10):

It looks like your initial answer is pretty close.

The following should work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'S'] != 0:
        df.loc[index, 'S'] = df.loc[str(int(index) - 1), 'S']
```

Essentially, for all but the first index, i.e. 0, change the value in the 'S' column to the value in the row before it. Note: This assumes a dataframe with a sequential, ordered index.

The `iterrows()` method doesn't let you modify the values by calling the row on its own, hence you need to use `df.loc()` to identify the cell in the dataframe and then change it's value.

Also worth noting that `index` is not an integer, hence the the use of the `int()` function to subtract 1. This is all within the `str()` function so that the final index output is a string, as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The point of `iterrows` is to operate one row at a time, so you won't be able to access prior rows.
Your function will be slow anyways, and there's a much faster way:

```
df['S_shifted'] = df.S.shift()

compared = pd.concat([df['A'] + df['S_shifted'] - df['B'], df['K']], axis=1)

df['S'] = compared.min(axis=1)

In [29]: df['S']
Out[29]: 
2012-03-31         NaN
2012-04-30    57.54449
2012-05-31    71.64000
2012-06-30    71.64000
Name: S, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be:

```
for (index, row), ii in zip(df.iterrows(), range(len(df.index))):
  # index: current row index
  # row: current row
  # df.iloc[ii-1]: prv row (of course make sure, prv row is present)
  # df.iloc[ii+1]: next row (of course make sure, next row is present)
```