# Access previous row while iterating on rows of a dataframe using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating through the rows of a dataframe using iterrows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    pass
```

Given that the index here contains datetime objects, how can we easily access the row at the previous index (i-1) while being at level index (i) ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas iterrows() with previous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473153/python-pandas-iterrows-with-previous-values)

Comment: Yes I have seen this before asking my question... and I am not so sure how they convert an datetime to int using int(index)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
row_ = None
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # processing logic here (use row_ as prev row and "row" as current)
    row_ = row
```

row_ will be None if index is 0 else it will be previous row.
This logic should work for any index type

Comment: was a type. fixed it :P. Other simple way is using row_ initialized as None out side loop and after using it, you can set row_ as row at the end of the loop

Comment: Well in fact df.iloc[index-1] doesnt work at my index is a datetime and not an integer

Comment: Editted that, it should work for any index